# Error C2440 '=' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'wchar_t'

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I got a little problem with my C++/CLI progamm.

I got a few `Char` arrays wo work without problems.

Header1:

```
  ref class _CGuid{ 
        static const int CIDGR=37;  
        public: 
        array<Char>^  cGuid;
        array<Char>^ cUuid;

           }
```

Cpp1 -> contruktor:

```
 cGuid = gcnew array<Char>(CIDGR);
```

some function:

```
_CGuid::Type(String^ tmpname,String^  tmpid)
{


pcName=tmpname;
cUuid=tmpid->ToCharArray();


}
```

So this Works Perfectly fine for me without errors.
How ever This *doesn’t* work:

Other Header:

```
ref class CStorage{
public:
array<String^>^ names;
array<Char>^ mac;
```

Other contruktor

```
names = gcnew array<String^>(100);
mac = gcnew array<Char>(100);
```

some function 2:

```
names[k]=tname;
mac[k]=tmac->ToCharArray(); <-------- Error Line
k++;
```

This line gets the error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from `cli::array<Type> ^` to `wchar_t`
>
> ```
>   with
>   [
>        Type=wchar_t
>   ]
> ```
>
> There is no context in which this conversion is possible

So I really don´t know whats the problem here.

Comment: So you're trying to set one position in `mac` with an entire array?  The error message make sense, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please format your source code properly to increase readability.

Comment: You cannot store a mac address in a Char.  Not in an array of Char either, a Char is *not* equivalent to a byte in managed code, that only works in C.  Get ahead with a `List<array<Byte>^>^`, a list of arrays of byte.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, actually. `ToCharArray` returns an `array<Char>`, which you try to assign to a single `Char` (= `wchar_t`) when accessing `mac[k]`.

Did you maybe mean to assign to `mac` instead?

```
mac = tmac->ToCharArray();
```

If so, then this line is redundant:

```
mac = gcnew array<Char>(100);
```

Here you allocate memory for `mac` which you later throw away when you re-assign `mac`.

Comment: thanks 4 your answers. I want to have a field (mac) wich can save up to 100 Mac adresses.

Answer (score 0):

here you copy a CLI array coming from the "ToCharArray" in 1 wchar_t of the Mac array!

```
  mac[k]=tmac->ToCharArray(); <-------- Error Line
```

as you want an array of Mac Address you must allocate it with

```
   mac = gcnew array<array<Char> >(100);
```

so now you can affect  mac[k]

Comment: I want to create a field wich can save up to 100 Macs.  (e.g. Like the name field). The Problem is that i have to "give Back" the e.g 20 Macs saved in the Mac arry